# How to create a symbol table?

Tags: c, symbol-tables

Can I use malloc to add symbol table entries?  How do I traverse the table to check if something is already there?

Comment: A little context, please. Are you working in C? Are you building a compiler? Is this homework? How large is your language? Do you use any libraries?

Comment: It's homework for a compiler class.  I'm using C.  The language is not very large.  No libraries are used.

Answer (score 5):

A "symbol table" doesn't describe a particular kind of data structure. It merely describes the primary modes of operation: adding symbols and retrieving symbols by name. Symbols here are basically attributed names. For a compiler class, one such an attribute could be `IsAFunction`.

C has very few built-in datastructures. You'd have to create one yourself in this case. In C++, it would just be a matter of a `std::map<std::string, Attributes>`. Now presumably if you're in a compiler class, you should already know how to implement datastructures in C (including the use of `malloc()`). If not, then a compiler class really isn't for you.

Answer (score 2):

In general, symbol tables are implemented through [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Hash tables have the advantage of O(1) store and retrieve, but they don't store data sequentially.

Assuming you're working in C you can uses `malloc()`, but it requires more work than that. The provided link should enlighten you.

Answer (score 0):

I'v done that with a double chained linked list before. But now i will definitively do it with a hashtable.
It's just a datastructure.